# build conda package with pip dependency and conda dependency

Tags: python, pip, package, conda, conda-build

I am using conda-build to build the package.

I have tried multiple option which are present on internet . but could not find better option.
tried writing script in meta.yml that also did not work

If anyone can mention the advantage and disadvantage of using conda for building the package that will also be helpful